# How to render Map in nested div View

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm trying to work out how to render a map inside a nested div. I have my component `Home.js`:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

import {Map, TileLayer} from "react-leaflet"


class Home extends Component {
    constructor(  )
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            latlng: {
                lat: 51.5074,
                lng: 0.1277,
            },
        }
    }

    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="main-wrap">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div id="content-wrap" style={{height:'700px'}}>
                    <Map
                        center={this.state.latlng}
                        length={4}
                        zoom={13}>
                        <TileLayer
                            attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />
                    </Map>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

But that doesn't render anything although I can see the component in the page if I use the React developer tools.

If I just have one div containing the map then it works fine. e.g.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

import {Map, TileLayer} from "react-leaflet"


class Home extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            latlng: {
                lat: 51.5074,
                lng: 0.1277,
            },
        }
    }

    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="main-wrap">

                <Map
                    center={this.state.latlng}
                    length={4}
                    zoom={13}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                </Map>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

But I'd quite like to include other stuff on the page as well, hence the multiple divs.

Thanks in advance if you can help.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't set this CSS:

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

All works now!